# Compatibility issue when using rails_admin_email gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I am using rails 4.2.1. I have already added **rails_admin** module in my app. Now, I want to add email facility for admin, so that he can send email to the users. For that, I  have added [**rails_admin_email**](https://github.com/320ny/rails_admin_email) gem.
But when I execute bundle install command some dependency issues occur

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
 In Gemfile:
   rails (= 4.2.1)

   rails_admin_email was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
     rails (~> 3.2.6)
```

How can I solve the issue?

Please also provide some useful hint, if there is a better way than using rails_admin_email gem

Here are my current [GemFile](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/487afc56e7d4cc25e83b574e61624ed0) and [Gemfile.lock](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/49fecc84fbe6dc547705175b736366c1) .

Comment: Can you share your Gemfile in a github gist/link

Comment: gem 'rails_admin_email', :git => "https://github.com/320ny/rails_admin_email.git"

Comment: Can you share the complete Gemfile and Gemfile.lock you have.

Comment: gist link added to the question. Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this answer should fix the problem i would not encourage you to use [rails_admin_email](https://github.com/320ny/rails_admin_email) as it has not been touched since **July 2012** and not present on [rubygems.org](http://rubygems.org) :). Still solution below.

---

The problem in this case is the dependencies defined

- [rails_admin_email](https://github.com/320ny/rails_admin_email) for rails is `s.add_dependency "rails", "~> 3.2.6"`
- [rails_admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) for rails is `s.add_dependency 'rails', ['>= 4.0', '< 6']`

To fix this problem you need to fork/pr [rails_admin_gem](https://github.com/320ny/rails_admin_email) to use `>= 3.2.6`. Here is [what i tried in my fork](https://github.com/ankit8898/rails_admin_email/commit/104c133fa446bb7f58de834bece29e8c7649be7b) and it works.

Comment: Is there a better option than rails_admin_email gem

Comment: how can I fix the issue of the gem

Comment: I have it fixed in my fork https://github.com/ankit8898/rails_admin_email you can try changing Gemfile to `gem 'rails_admin_email', :git => "https://github.com/ankit8898/rails_admin_email.git"`

Comment: Is there a better option for sending email to users for rails_admin

Comment: I think you can create a stanadlone action mailer in your code and register as a actions. You can see what rails_admin_email was doing. https://github.com/320ny/rails_admin_email/blob/master/lib/rails_admin_email.rb

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: I want to add a separate view not under any model actions. Is there any option to do it